# Script php e ajax não roda na minha maquina

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estou fazendo uma sistema de cadastro e para isso estou usando o php e ajax, fiz as duas paginas corretamente acredito, quando executo o script as validações que coloquei no php executam perfeitamente e retorna sucesso, porém quando verifico o banco de dados nenhum dado foi inserido, faço outros insert no banco e funciona normalmente, eu achava que o código estava errado porém executei o mesmo projeto em uma outra maquia com o mesmo script do banco e rodou, testei isso várias vezes e em todas rodou nessa outra maquina, esse cadastro é a unica parte do meu projeto que hora funciona hora não funciona, alguém pode me dar uma luz ? agradeço desde já.

```
Classe


<?php


   class anuncio {

        private $cd_anuncio;
        private $dt_criacao;
        private $nm_titulo;
        private $ds_anuncio;
        private $cd_usuario;
        private $nm_estado;
        private $nm_cidade;
        private $nm_bairro;




        public function anuncio($nm_titulo,$ds_anuncio,$cd_usuario,$nm_estado,$nm_cidade,$nm_bairro)
        {
            $this->nm_titulo=$nm_titulo;
            $this->ds_anuncio=$ds_anuncio;
            $this->cd_usuario=$cd_usuario;
            $this->nm_estado=$nm_estado;
            $this->nm_cidade=$nm_cidade;
            $this->nm_bairro=$nm_bairro;

        }

        public function AddAnuncio()
        {
            include("conexao.php");

            $query = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO tb_anuncio(dt_criacao,nm_titulo,ds_anuncio,cd_usuario,nm_estado,nm_cidade,nm_bairro) VALUES (NOW(),'$this->nm_titulo','$this->ds_anuncio','$this->cd_usuario','$this->nm_estado','$this->nm_cidade','$this->nm_bairro')");
               $result = $conexao->query($query);
                  return $result;



        }

         public function Ver()
         {


            return "data: $this->dt_criacao title: $this->nm_titulo Desc : $this->ds_anuncio CD : $this->cd_usuario ESTADO : '$this->nm_estado CIDADE: $this->nm_cidade Bairro : $this->nm_bairro";
         }






   }




?>
```

**php que se comunica com o ajax**

```
<?php 

session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
include_once("usuario_class.php");

    require_once("conexao.php");
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $telefone_fixo = $_POST['telefone'];
    $telefone_movel = $_POST['celular'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];


$verifica = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE nm_email = '$email' AND cd_senha = '$senha'") or die("erro ao selecionar");     
        if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<=0)
        {
    if(isset($_POST['terms']))
    {
    if(isset($nome,$sobrenome,$email,$sexo,$telefone_fixo,$telefone_movel,$senha) AND is_numeric($telefone_fixo) AND is_numeric($telefone_movel))
        {
            $objeto_usu = new usuario($nome,$sobrenome,$telefone_fixo,$telefone_movel,$email,$sexo,$senha);
                if($objeto_usu->AddUsuario())
                {
            // retornando ao sucesso no registro
            echo"rodou";
                }
            }
            else{
                // retornando ao ajax dados inválidos
              echo"3";
            }
        }
        else{
            // retornando ao ajax checkd false
               echo"2";
        }
    }
else{
    // retornando ao ajax email já cadastrado
   echo"1";
    }
?>
```

**Script ajax**

< !-- jquey para registro do usuario do login-->

```
        $(function(){
        var url = '../ibico/php/insere_usuario.php';
        function carregando()
        {
            $('.loadCadastro').fadeIn('slow');
        }
            $('.cadastroUsuario').submit(function(){            
                var dados = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                  url:url,
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: dados,
                  beforeSend: carregando,
                  success: function(retorno){



                    if(retorno==1)
                    {
                    $('.emailCadastrado').html("Email já cadastrado !");
                    $('.loadCadastro').fadeOut('slow');

                    } else if (retorno==2)
                    {
                    $('.emailCadastrado').html("É preciso aceitar os termos para continuar !");
                    $('.loadCadastro').fadeOut('slow');



                    } else if (retorno==3)
                    {

                      $('.emailCadastrado').html("Preencha apenas números nos campos telefone e celular");
                      $('.loadCadastro').fadeOut('slow');

                    } else

                    {

                     $('.emailCadastrado').html("");

                      alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso !");
                     window.location.href ="index.html";


                    }



                // alert(retorno);

              // window.location.href ="index.html#modalentrar";

                 }

        });
      return false;
     });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: O que não funciona exatamente? O Ajax? O Ajax está retornando as mensagens?

Comment: O ajax funciona e da retorno, o que não está funcionando acredito que seja o php, só que testei em outra maquina varias vezes o mesmo script e funcionou, já fiz e refiz esse codigo umas 3 vezes funciona e depois volta a dar erro não sei o que está acontecendo sera que pode ser minha maquina ?

Comment: meu mysql as vezes apresenta algumas mensagens de erro, passei a utilizar apenas o phpmyadmin mas não tive sucesso